# chrome extension chrome.webNavigation (Event) fires multiple time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome extension , I need to create a function to detect the URL changes for example `youtube.com` to `youtube.com/watch?v={some video id}`

I kept looking around for a way to do that on `Content.js` but apparently it's not possible and i need to use `background.js` in that particular case

First I've implanted this part

```
chrome.webNavigation.((EVENT)).addListener(function() {
   alert("worked");
});
```

to test if chrome can detect the URL changes correctly , then i will need to connect that to `content.js` to `Ajax` the `URL` changes and return `JSON` object from the server

I saw on this page [Chrome Extension - webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) multiple **Events** that i can use

**Events**

- onBeforeNavigate
- onCommitted
- onDOMContentLoaded
- onCompleted
- onErrorOccurred
- onCreatedNavigationTarget
- onReferenceFragmentUpdated
- onTabReplaced
- onHistoryStateUpdated

sadly none of them works properly as they the `Alert` pops Multiple times ( sometimes 1-4 times ) when i visit ( reload or visit a single page )

I don't know what i should do or if there is any other way to handle a problem like this , I'm fairly new to chrome extension and `JS`.

**background.js**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get( "extensionSwitch", function(data){
  if( data[ "extensionSwitch" ] == undefined ){
    chrome.storage.sync.set( { "extensionSwitch" : "true" }, function() {  } );
  }

});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  fetch(request.input, request.init).then(function(response) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
      sendResponse([{
        body: text,
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
      }, null]);
    });
  }, function(error) {
    sendResponse([null, error]);
  });
  return true;
});

chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function() {
   alert("worked");
});
```

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) and [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: window.addEventListener("spfdone", process); // old youtube design
window.addEventListener("yt-navigate-start", process); // new youtube design
both of them works only (( if i've pasted url in the browser )) youtube , i need a function to run whenever URL changes

Comment: `yt-navigate-start` works for every video navigation, but for "history back" navigation you need to use the standard `"popstate"` event.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks alot but what if iam on google and have just visited youtube , it doesn't fire at all , only if i'm only on youtube and navigating

Comment: Simply run process() directly at the start of your content script in addition to yt-navigate-start.